# Data-centric application: separate database tables for separate organizations a good idea?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am building an application where several organizations can register
themselves and manipulate a set of enterprise tables such as list of
clients, sellers, items, sale orders etc... I was wondering whether
rather than have a single set of tables, it would be much safer to
have a separate set of tables for each client, all running within
the same database. For instance, the database could have the
following schema:

```
JOHNDOEFIRM_CUSTOMERS
JOHNDOEFIRM_CLIENTS
JOHNDOEFIRM_ORDERS
...

JAKEDOESONFIRM_CUSTOMERS
JAKEDOESONFIRM_CLIENTS
JAKEDOESONFIRM_ORDERS
...
```

and so on, with one set of tables for each firm. The tables would be
created each time a firm registers, with the appropriate prefix.
This could have the following advantages:

1. it would be safer if a firm cannot mess up another firm's table by accident
2. firm-specific customizations to the table would be made

What are the advantages of doing this, versus keeping a separate database
altogether for each firm? Since each firm will have around 20-40 tables,
will the number of tables tend to explode in magnitude with number of
users, thus slowing down the database altogether?

Any feedback on the design of the application just described and the issues
I am pointing out in this post would be very very welcome, as well as suggestions
of dos and don'ts.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the application instance also shared?

Comment: There's a third option where you can have multiple databases, but also have multiple firms in each (e.g. 5 firms per database).

Comment: Each firm will have its own application instance. There is another advantages to keeping the tables separate, which is, that different firms can use different versions of the firm software and customizations can be made on a per-firm basis by keeping the tables separate. I've seen one site use a login form where the firm name, user name, and password are required to access the system instread of just a username and password. That way the firm name can be used to select the appropriate database (or database prefix, but I think I'll go with the simple design of one database per firm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering whether rather than have a single set of tables, it would be much safer to have a separate set of tables for each client, all running within the same database.

If you want to do this, you have a separate set of tables for each client, running in different logical databases.  It's easier for the DBAs to manage.

You're basically admitting that you can't depend on your application code to keep the firms separate when sharing the same database tables.

> Since each firm will have around 20-40 tables, will the number of tables tend to explode in magnitude with number of users, thus slowing down the database altogether?

You're either going to have 20 - 40 tables for each firm, or 20 - 40 large tables for all the firms.  The amount of storage will be about the same either way.

If each firm has it's own logical database, the DBAs have flexibility to move firms to new physical databases.  Say you can put the tables of 5 firms on a server.  In other words, 5 logical databases per physical database.  Then your DBAs know how many servers to manage.

If a particular firm causes proportionally more database problems, the logical database for that firm can be moved to its own physical database until the problems are sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe is commonly known as "multi-tenant architecture". There are no right or wrong answers - but there are a whole bunch of trade-offs.

Your design - table namespace per client - has the benefits you mention. Each client has their own fenced-off set of tables, so it's hard for any one client to affect another's data, and you can apply different versions to different clients. Drawbacks are pretty horrible though - every time you change the application, you end up changing hundreds of clients' tables. If you have common data - currencies, countries of the world, sizes - you have to either duplicate those across clients (JOHNDOE_COUNTRIES) or have a single one which breaks the "all of John Doe's tables are called JOHNDOE_" consistency. A single bug - especially a performance issue in your queries - scales to the number of clients you have, and has to be fixed for every single client. In your application code, you have to spend time changing the name of each database table, which makes many ORM solutions harder to work with.

The alternative option mentioned here - database per client - is far more elegant. You keep the separation between clients, you can put different clients on different physical hardware to manage performance/scalability, you don't have to mangle the table names in your application code, and your build/deployment scripts are far simpler. However, you still have the whole "make the same code change once for every client" problem. It becomes a problem very, very quickly - if your build/deploy script takes 10 minutes, by the time you have 200 clients, it would take all day to upgrade your application.

You can, of course, bake the client_id into the database schema - have CLIENT_ID as a column in CLIENTS, ORDERS etc. This means that a bug in your code means one client can affect another client's data - but that possibility still exists in the other scenarios. The code which mangles the table names in option one could contain a bug which selects the wrong client prefix, for instance.

However, a single large database with lots client_id to identify which client "owns" the data is *much* easier to manage - a single build/deploy script, fixing and testing bugs can happen just once, new features are rolled out just the once. This cost saving is potentially huge.

So, my recommendation would be to have a single database with CLIENT_ID to begin with, but bake in the option to select a different database for each client so you can scale to multiple databases in the future. I would not use a different table for each client.

Comment: Hello. You mention that an application upgrade implies having to change the tables of every single client, thus requiring quite a lot of code. Instead, what I was thinking, is why not have the client upgrade the database to the next version. So when the client chooses to upgrade, a new database is created, tables are migrated, and then the old database is deleted. This way the client has control over the version number and takes their own time to do the upgrade.

Comment: The situation is different of course if there is a bug rather than a feature enhancement, which means an upgrade must take place immediately. However, given I can have my own databse for testing purposes, this should make bugs less likely. So for each different database schema I can have a test database which looks exactly the same.

Comment: What I would like to do is set up a script which generates the user interface from the data present in the database schema definition files and push it to each client according to their own needs.

Comment: Given that I will be storing other databases from other applications on the same server, I will create each database with the application name followed by an underscore followed by a name identifying the particular collection of database tables according to the schema they use (so each schema can have a different name, so clients with the same needs get the same schema name, but clients with different needs get different schema names) and then I want to follow the schema name with a version number, so clients can upgrade from one version to another. These three parts will comprise the db name.

Comment: The comments you post are way more than I can answer - but in brief, writing "a script which generates the user interface from the data present in the database" is a massive, awe-inspiring task, far bigger than splitting your data between clients. In general, I think it's a bad idea to have to make a schema change for a predictable business event...